# Copying an ID when registering an user in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I want to copy the content of id into owner_id after someone registers.

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('owner_id');
```

How do I do this? I have tried this which I obviously expected not to work:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ...
        'owner_id' => $data['id'],


    ]);
}
```

Since $data only gives you the form information. I am clueless now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create user first. Only then you can use it's ID:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);

$user->update(['ownder_id' => $user->id]);
```

Comment: The other 2 solutions work too. I just went with this. In case someone else looks at this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']);
$user->owner_id = $user->id;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

> First create the user then update the `ownder_id` by
>   `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();` or `$user->id`.

Try this,

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    User::where('id', $user->id)
        ->update(['ownder_id' => $user->id]);
    return $user;
}
```